# Convert local master into a branch in git

Tags: git, github

I cloned a github repository and made several commits locally. I accidentally made these commits on the master branch when I had intended to make a separate branch for my changes. Is there some way to turn these changes into a new branch and restore the original master branch before I push my changes to the remote?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. # create a new branch from your current HEAD:

   ```
   git branch <newbranchname>
   ```
2. # reset your current branch (still master) to the remote master branch:

   ```
   git reset --hard origin/master
   ```
3. # switch to the new branch:

   ```
   git checkout <newbranchname>
   ```

Comment: Incidentally, if you wanted to do this in two steps, you could `$ git reset --hard origin/master && git checkout -b newbranchname HEAD@{1}`. I <3 reflogs.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ git branch new-branch-name
$ git reset --hard origin/master ## or whatever point you want to reset master to
```

Comment: Please elaborate your solution/steps